# How to find branch point of $z^z$

Tags: complex-analysis, exponentiation

Regarding question relating to branches as shown below:

Consider the multi-valued operation $z^z$. How do I find the branch points and all its possible value at $z=1$?

Thanks for helping me everybody

Answer (score 0):

The only possible value is $1$, since $1^1=\exp(1\times\log 1)$, where $\log(1)$ is some logarithm of $1$. But the logarithms of $1$ are the numbers of the form $2k\pi i$ ($k\in\mathbb Z$), and therefore, as I wrote, $1^1=\exp(2k\pi i)=1$.

Comment: lets say if z is a complex number does your answer still holds???

Comment: @john If $z=1$, yes. Otherwise, it depends upon the number.

Comment: sorry, I start to get confused because I thought branch points are supposed to be points where it is zero or infinity?? So for this case if z=1, wouldn't it not fulfil the zero or infinity criteria??

Comment: @john A branch point is a point such that if you go in a loop around it, you end elsewhere then where you started. A branch cut is what you use to make sense of this fact.

Comment: apologies.. what I mean is branch cut

Comment: @john Branch cuts appear when the function is multivalued. However, in this specific case, the fact that $\log$ is multivalued doesn't change the value of $1^1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos why is zero not part of the possible values??

Comment: @john Of $z^z$? No.